# ASP.NET Convention Based Naming

Tags: .net, asp.net, windows

Could someone explain ASP.NET Convention Based Naming and provide some examples if possible please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convention-based naming is essentially a way to reduce the amount of explicit code you have to write by defining a set of convention mappings so that, for example, pages whose names match a certain format will be automatically looked for within a certain directory.

There's an article [here](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part4.htm) which has some examples (have a search for '*Convention-based naming and the \Views directory structure*') and another from the same series [here](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part7.htm).

There's another, more concise example here: [ASP.NET MVC: When convention really matters](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2009/04/07/aspnet-mvc-where-convention-really-matters/).

In that example, calling `return View("NotFound");` from the `DinnersController` class will automatically look for a View called `NotFound` in the `\Views\Dinners\` directory, without you needing to explicitly define that directory structure when you call `View()`.

The convention in this instance determines the location of the `View` based on the name of the `Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

[Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx)

[Guidelines for Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx)

All primary sources from Microsoft.

Comment: Those are naming conventions, not convention-based naming.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any ASP.NET examples, but ASP.NET MVC certainly uses conventions. One example, is that a request to `\Report\View` is automatically mapped to a controller called `ReportController` containing a method called `View()`. There's no need to do any other wiring - just ending your class name with `Controller` is enough.